# Converting JSON field with array index as keys into an array field

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion

I have a situation where I need to get information from a server (SA) which in turn gets it from another server (SB). SA responds with a JSON result but looking at the response it appears that SB responds with XML from a SOAP API and SA is converting XML to JSON before sending it back.

A sample response from SA is as below:

```
{
    fieldA : "some string", // "hello stackoverflow"
    fieldB : JSON object, // {"a" : "b" , "cd" : "ef" }
    fieldC : JSON object with fields representing array indices // { "0": "interesting" , "1" : "not helpful" }
}
```

I don't know what the "`fieldA`", "`fieldB`" etc in the root will be when I get the response, and neither do I know the depth of a JSON field.

So I made a recursive function as below and it works for the sample data that I have. Is there something that I am overlooking here that can break this loop or is there a more optimized version of this?

```
var prunedResponse = (function prune(obj){
    let val = new Object();
    for(let [k,v] of Object.entries(obj)){
        if( k !== "attributes" ){
            if( typeof v !== 'object' ) val[k] = v;
            else if( !Object.keys(v).filter( _k => isNaN(_k*1) ).length ) val[k] = Object.values(v).map(_v => prune(_v));
            else val[k] = prune(v);
        }
    }
    return val;
})(responseData);
```

Below is the desired output

```
{
    fieldA : "some string",
    fieldB : { "a" : "b" , "cd" : "ef" },
    fieldC : [ "interesting" , "not helpful" ]
}
```

Comment: you haven't described what the `prune` should actually do. providing a concrete input/output example would enable us to help you more effectively

Comment: @Thankyou .. As I said in the title of the question, the basic objective is to go through the entire JSON object however deep nested it is and if there is any field that has numbers as keys, convert that field into an array instead while everything else intact. Ex. convert `{"y":{"x":{"0":"a","1":b"},"z":"alpha"}}` into `{"y":{x:["a","b"],"z":"alpha"}}` . [Edit: added desired output in the question]

Answer (score 2):

You could break early when checking if any key is non-numeric by doing

```
if( !Object.keys(v).some( _k => isNaN(_k*1) ) )
```

instead of

```
if( !Object.keys(v).filter( _k => isNaN(_k*1) ).length )
```

Also, for your example `fieldC` your code will break as your `prune` expects an object and you pass a string `.map(_v => prune(_v));` and you will convert each string to an array.

You should add an initial check to return early the non object value passed.

```
var prunedResponse = (function prune(obj){
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') return obj;
    let val = new Object();
    for(let [k,v] of Object.entries(obj)){
        if( k !== "attributes" ){
            if( typeof v !== 'object' ) val[k] = v;
            else if( !Object.keys(v).some( _k => isNaN(_k*1) ) ) val[k] = Object.values(v).map(_v => prune(_v));
            else val[k] = prune(v);
        }
    }
    return val;
})(responseData);
```

The final possible issue i see is for the case where some `fieldC` type data is not continuous. If for example it has `{'1':'some', '4':'some-other'}` should you handle it as an array ? (*currently you will create different indices*)

Comment: Thanks. `{'1':'some', '4':'some-other'}` this part is fine as all the fields are serialized. `fieldC` error you mentioned is already taken care of by the first `if` clause where it checks if a field value is not an object. However, I did face one issue on NodeJS but not in the browser. If a field value is a timestamp, the browser is treating it as a string, but NodeJS is treating it as an object and returning an empty array.

Comment: regarding the `fieldC` your original code fails when the indexed values are strings. You `prune` will always return an `object`  (`let val = new Object();`). But you called in a map for each value in the indexed object, so it will fail if those are string.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what loop you're looking to break.

Here is an alternative implementation.  I'm not saying it's any better.  It is simply more suited to my programming style.  You may or may not find it interesting:

```js
const prune = (o) =>
  Object (o) === o
    ?  Object .keys (o) .every (k => !isNaN (k * 1))
      ? Object .values (o) .map (prune)
      : Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o)
          .filter (([k, v]) => k !== 'attributes')
          .map (([k, v]) => [k, prune (v)])
        )
    : o

const input = {attributes: "ignore", fieldA : "hello stackoverflow", fieldB : {"a" : "b" , "cd" : "ef"}, fieldC : {"0": {some: {"0": "foo", "3": "bar"}} , "1": "not helpful"}}

console .log (prune (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If you do need to deal gaps in your indices, as mentioned in another answer, you could replace this line:

```js
      ? Object .values (o) .map (prune)
```

with something like this:

```js
      ? Object.assign([], Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o) .map(([k, v]) => [k, prune(v)])))
```

I might also extract a helper function

```js
const isIndexed = (o) =>
  Object .keys (o) .every (k => !isNaN (k * 1))
```

and use it in place of the first nested test.

Comment: Interesting indeed. Always good to learn new methods for getting things done. I'll keep this as a reference for my future projects when dealing with XML and SOAP APIs in javascript.

Comment: @HymnZzy this is a generic object transformation not limited to things XML, SOAP, or other API calls. It can be used on all JavaScript objects.

Comment: @Thankyou .. Yes I am aware of it, but I found this type of structure coincidentally only in the samples relating to XML to JSON conversions libraries and modules.

Comment: Do note, though that the removal of `attributes` nodes is less generic, and it would probably have been better to write this in two passes, one to compress indexed objects into arrays and a second one to remove the attributes, built atop a generic remove-this-property-name-at-every-level function.